# Is there anyway to use the SetCursorPos(int, int) function but instead of taking two int make it take two doubles for slower speed

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make an Xbox controller move the cursor is there anyway I can use the setCursorPos() function and increment by two doubles instead of two ints. The problem is that 1 is still too fast of a change.

Comment: _"still too fast"_: huh??

Answer (score 3):

`SetCursorPos()` doesn't increment the cursor, it moves it to a new absolute x/y location. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) for a description. And no, you can't call it with float params, it takes int params.

You did not provide any code, so making comments on other ways to do it is impossible. If you are incrementing the location such as e.g.

```
 x = x+1;
 x = y+1;
 SetCursoPos(x,y);
```

then to make it move slower you can simply add a delay between successive calls to `SetCursorPos()`.

Answer (score 1):

For reliable input injection you should be using [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead of `SetCursorPos`. This ensures that the system performs the entire pipeline of input processing, keeping applications happy. Setting the [`MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmouseinput) flags allows you to pass normalized coordinates in the range of [0..65535]. In the vast majority of cases this provides a higher resolution than the display device; essentially this allows to use sub-pixel precision.